# Does the generalized homology represented by the sphere spectrum give the stable homotopy groups on suspension spectra of pointed spaces?

Tags: algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy-theory, spectra

If $\mathbb{S}$ is the sphere spectrum, I would like to show that [the generalized homology theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stable+homotopy+category#idea) represented by $\mathbb{S}$, when evaluated on the [suspension spectrum](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/suspension+spectrum#definition) $\Sigma^\infty X$ of a pointed ("nice"?) topological space $X$,
gives the stable homotopy groups of $X$. That is, we claim
$$
\big( \mathbb{S}_*(\Sigma^\infty X) \big)_n
 \simeq \pi^{\mathrm{stable}}_n(X)
$$
where the LHS uses the notation in the 1st link.

When I unraveled the definitions (using the nLab definition of the [smash product](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sequential+spectrum#SmashProduct) of sequential spectra), this became the claim that
$$
\pi^{\mathrm{stable}}_n(X) 
\simeq \pi_{2k}(S^{k-n}\wedge \Sigma^k X) \simeq \pi_{2k+1}(S^{k+1-n} \wedge \Sigma^k X)
$$
for sufficiently large $k$. Here $\wedge$ is the smash product.

Is there a way to show the above holds? Or, is my assumption incorrect that the sphere spectrum should produce the stable homotopy groups of $X$? (Do we need to replace the suspension pre-spectrum of $X$ by its spectrification, as mentioned [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/suspension+spectrum#properties)?) (Or also, do I have a mistake in my calculations?)

---

(Edit: removed an earlier incorrect edit per the suggestions in the comments.)

Comment: Your edit is really really false. Perhaps you are missing a colimit in some of your definitions...

Comment: @ConnorMalin I see, thank you for pointing this out. I've removed the incorrect edit.